# Class which encapsulates related socket streams

Tags: java, io, socket, stream

I have a class which encapsulates stream related objects, and I have provided the method API for doing basic manipulation on the stream read/write/close, but is this a good approach? The only benefit I can see is that if for some reason one wants to use other stream classes at a later point in the project, one can just replace the stream objects in the custom class, without touching the users of the stream, or create an interface for the users and another class which implements other stream objects. For my purposes I need stream objects which can read `String` messages, but maybe later would need to read byte chunks also.

```
public class MessageInputOutput {
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private BufferedReader reader;

    /**
     * Create an IO stream.
     * @param socketRef    Client socket reference.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public MessageInputOutput(Socket socketRef) throws IOException {
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socketRef.getOutputStream()));
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketRef.getInputStream()));
    }

    /**
     * Read message.
     * @return    Message string.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String readMessage() throws IOException {
        return reader.readLine();
    }

    /**
     * Write message
     * @param message    Message string.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void writeMessage(String message) throws IOException {
        writer.println(message);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Close IO stream.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void closeMessageStream() throws IOException {
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```